# I am getting this error. The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later

Tags: facebook, messaging

I was try from my localhost. my server is nginx that is secure by SSL. I was follow the right instruction and get this error. Any one tell me how to fix it ? Please check the image. I am getting the error

[image: img]

Comment: A callback URL is an address that Facebook will make a request _to_, from their servers. Obviously that can only work with URLs publicly available on the internet, and not your local dev machine

Comment: @CBroe I have also try by the real domain and that is hosted shared hosting. getting the same error.

Comment: The verification of a webhook URL happens via a GET request - could be that Facebook _replaces_ the URL parameter you already got in there, with its own, instead of merging them. Try with a URL that does not use GET parameters.